# Trying to hookup 10-15 laptops to a switch, could someone point me in the right direction?

Tags: networking, nat, switch

Let me start off by saying I am not a system administrator, however I am desktop client support. I have the need to have about 10-15 laptops to be hooked up to a switch that gives all 10-15 laptops internet access. This switch is plugged into the wallport and does have internet access with a static IP I have given it. The laptops do not have static IPs. I think what I want is NAT, however I am not too familiar with this or how to set it up. I have a HP 1810G 24 Port switch that I am trying to make it work with, however I cannot seem to get it to work (If this will even suffice for what I need). I would preferably need to make it work with this switch (If possible). I also have a Juniper SRX240 if that would also work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not being provided DHCP through the wall LAN port you'll have to do one of the following:

- Connect a switch to the wall LAN port and configure a static IP, gateway, netmask, and DNS servers on each computer.  Each computer will require its own static IP.
- Connect a router to the wall LAN port and use it to provide NAT for the computers.

I'm guessing you don't want to go through all of the work for the first option, plus your network team might not be willing to provide that many static IPs.  So you could do the following for the second option:

[image]

You can use any commodity/consumer grade router and switches.  If you cannot get a single switch with enough ports you can use multiple switches and connect them to the router or daisy chain them.

Connect the WAN port of the router to the wall LAN port and configure the static IP, netmask, gateway, and DNS servers your network team provides you.

On the LAN side of the router have it provide DHCP services.  You can most likely use the default private subnet settings.  Very likely something like 192.168.0.0/24 or 10.0.0.0/24.

Comment: Gene, I did it exactly like you said and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much, I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Excellent!  Please mark this answer as accepted, or if someone else comes along with a better answer mark theirs.

Answer (score 3):

So many things:

Switches don't give computers internet access. Switches provide physical connectivity to the physical network.

Routers give computers internet access.

Your computers all need to have a valid ip address configuration.

If the switch has internet access then most of the work is already done. All you need to do is to give the computers a valid ip address configuration, either via DHCP or via manually configured settings.

Who manages this network?

Comment: To the OP: One fine point here: "by valid ip address configuration", this doesn't just mean a valid IP address. They'll also need DNS and, more importantly, a correct default route that points to the router.

Comment: This is managed by a large university admin team, I wanted to try this by myself before I got them involved as I need this relatively soon. And through them it would take a while. I was told by them I could set up a NAT with a switch. The area I am in is not setup for DHCP, so that is out of the question.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: Thanks for the assist. I implied but didn't explicitly state: ip address, subnet mask, default gateway, dns servers.

Comment: @joeqwerty so essentially I cannot do what I want (Where the laptops do NOT have a valid IP configuration) with the equipment I have. I would need a router to do this

Comment: What I'm saying is that the laptops need two essential things: `1.` A connection to the physical network, which you already have. `2.` A valid ip configuration for your network, to include an ip address, subnet mask, default gateway and dns servers. A router on it's own doesn't help you if the laptops don't have a valid ip configuration.

Comment: Strictly speaking, switches don't do NAT. NAT occurs at Layer 3, switches operate at Layer 2

Comment: the juniper srx is fully featured and can serve as router, dhcp server and do all the things you want. if there aren't enough ports on the srx, plug the switch into the srx and the laptops into the switch.